# error with joining two lines in autocad using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, join, entity, line, autocad

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.DocumentExtension

    Namespace sweeping
        Public Class Testing
            <CommandMethod("jointwolines")>
            Public Shared Sub jointwolines()


                Dim line1, line2 As Line
                Dim pll As polyline


                Dim doc As Document = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument
                Dim db As Database = doc.Database
                Dim ed As Editor = doc.Editor
                Dim bt As BlockTable
                Dim btr As BlockTableRecord

                Using tr As Transaction = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()

                    line1 = New line(New point3d(0, 0, 0), New point3d(100, 0, 0))
                    line2 = New line(New point3d(100, 0, 0), New point3d(100, 100, 0))

                    bt = tr.GetObject(db.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead)
                    btr = tr.GetObject(bt(BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace), OpenMode.ForWrite)
                    pll = line1.joinentity(line2)

                    btr.AppendEntity(pll)
                    tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(pll, True)
                    tr.Commit()

                End Using
            End Sub
        End Class
    End Namespace
```

Part of my autocad customization requires me to join two lines into an entity. I have been trying really hard to get it done. But, I m facing a few obstacles.

The first one:
pll = line1.joinentity(line2) 
the line above gives me a warning 'expression does not produce a value'.
What I understand is that the joinentity function returns void, so I cant assign it to the pll of polyline type. However, I need to write the polyline formed by joining two lines to the autocad database. How do I go about achieving that?

Second one:
Whenever I build and debug the code to test it with Autocad, the same line
pll = line1.joinentity(line2)
will generate error and break the code. I tried to understand the error message, but to no avail. It reads

*An exception of type 'Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.Exception' occurred in AcdbMgd.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: eNotApplicable
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.*

How to solve this problem? Can someone please explain and help me?

Edited code(but problem still persist):

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Drawing
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.DocumentExtension
Namespace sweeping
            Public Class Testing
                <CommandMethod("jointwolines")>
                Public Shared Sub jointwolines()


                    Dim line1as polyline
                    Dim line2 As Line

 Dim doc As Document = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument
                    Dim db As Database = doc.Database
                    Dim ed As Editor = doc.Editor
                    Dim bt As BlockTable
                    Dim btr As BlockTableRecord

                    Using tr As Transaction = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()

                line1 = New Polyline()
                line1.AddVertexAt(0, New Point2d(0, 0), 0, 0, 0)
                line1.AddVertexAt(0, New Point2d(100, 0), 0, 0, 0)
                line1.Elevation = 0
                line2 = New Line(new point3d(0,0,0), new point3d(0,0,100))

               bt = tr.GetObject(db.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead)
               btr = tr.GetObject(bt(BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace), OpenMode.ForWrite)

              btr.AppendEntity(line1)
                line1.JoinEntity(line2)
                tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(line1, True)
                tr.Commit()
            End Using
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Can someone help me? This is getting frustrating :(

Comment: Without going in to Code, In AutoCAD you can't just add lines to a line. you first need to convert the (base) line to a Polyline, then you can add lines to them.  Hope this gives you a direction to solve your problem.

Comment: I tried changing line1 to polyline. But still has the same error.

Comment: still the same exception? Usually one entity cannot contain others until is appended to the database. So first add the pline to the BTR, then call pline.JoinEntity(line)

Comment: Hi, I changed the code slightly, but the problem still persists. I added the amended code to my question.

Answer (score 1):

`JoinEntity` does not create a new entity, it modifies the entity on which it is called. It's why you cannot get a return value.

Two lines can be joined if there are collinear, which is not your case. You need to call this method on a polyline, like you do in your second code snippet.

From the Autodesk doc :

> `Polyline.JoinEntity(ies)` requires the given entities to be other,
>   unclosed Polyline or Polyline2d, Line, and/or Arc entities, which
>   share common start or end points.

But `Polyline` is a 2D entity, lying in the XY plane of the WCS by default, and you try to add a line with an end point which is 100 units above this XY plane. You need to use a `Polyline3d`:

```
<CommandMethod("JOINTWOLINES")>
Public Shared Sub JoinTwoLines()
  Dim doc As Document = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument
  Dim db As Database = doc.Database

  Using tr As Transaction = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()
    Dim bt As BlockTable
    bt = tr.GetObject(db.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead)

    Dim btr As BlockTableRecord
    btr = tr.GetObject(bt(BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace), OpenMode.ForWrite)

    Dim pl as Polyline3d
    pl = New Polyline3d(Poly3dType.SimplePoly, _
                         new Point3dCollection(), _
                         False)
    btr.AppendEntity(pl)
    tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(pl, True)

    Dim line1 As Line
    line1 = New Line(New Point3d(0, 0, 0), New Point3d(100, 0, 0))
    btr.AppendEntity(line1)
    tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(line1, True)

    Dim line2 As Line
    line2 = New Line(new Point3d(0, 0, 0), new Point3d(0, 0, 100))
    btr.AppendEntity(line2)
    tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(line2, True)

    pl.JoinEntities(new Entity(){line1, line2})

    tr.Commit()
  End Using
End Sub
```

One more thing: do not put your variable at the top of your sub. You're not writing Pascal but C#. [Declare your variables where there are used.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113262/why-declare-variables-close-to-where-they-are-used)

Comment: Hi, thanks for you help. So, you are basically implying that I cant add the line that has non-zero Z-coordinate to the polyline lying in XY plane to form a new polyine3d. Am I right? If I am, is there a way to overcome this problem? I am asking because my plug in need to achieve joining those two lines to maximise efficiency.

Comment: For example, I can create the polyline in XY plane and rotate 90degrees about the X-axis.

Comment: Thanks a lot. this really saved me, and thanks for the advice too, as I am not familiar with both AutoCAD API and VB.NET.